# Unable to diagnose invalid syntax error (python)

Tags: python, error-handling

[image]

I have an invalid syntax error popping up on line 55. I think the problem is being caused earlier in the code, but I am unable to diagnose it. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is maybe due to the alignment of the except URLERROR, e which is not at the same level as try and the except block before.

Comment: Thank you. I messed around with indentation, just not at that line.